# Can't get the key of an entity after adding range of them

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I tried to add an IEnumerable to my DB, and then, after saving the changes, to get their key (id).
If I add only one entity (no collection), then the id is automaticaly populated after SaveChanges(), but in the collection - this doesn't work.

Here is the Add(OrUpdate) method(s) from the Repository:

```
private void Add(IEnumerable<LabLineEntity> p_lines)
    {
        foreach (var line in p_lines)
        {
            line.isActive = true;
        }
//assume this gets a main-work from the context, all line are related to a specific work
        LabMainEntity labMain = GetSpecific<LabMainEntity>(p_lines.First().AssignedToWork);

        m_context.LabLines.AddRange(p_lines);

        foreach (var line in p_lines) // adds to the ICollection
        {
            labMain.Lines.Add(line);
        }
    }
public void AddOrUpdate(IEnumerable<LabLineEntity> p_labLines)
    {
        if (!LinesAreLegal(p_labLines))
        {
            throw new Exception("Lab lines are not legal!");
        }
        var newLabLines = p_labLines.Where(l => l.Id == Guid.Empty);
        var existingLabLines = p_labLines.Where(l => l.Id != Guid.Empty);
        LabMainEntity labMain = GetSpecific<LabMainEntity>(p_labLines.First().AssignedToWork);
        if (existingLabLines.Any())
        {
            HashSet<Guid> existingLineIds = new HashSet<Guid>(existingLabLines.Select(l => l.Id));
            // from all the lines in the main, select those that are NOT in the lines to update.
            // this will return the lines that should be removed!
            HashSet<Guid> linesToRemove = new HashSet<Guid>(labMain.Lines.Where(ell => !existingLineIds.Contains(ell.Id)).Select(t=>t.Id));
            foreach (var lineGuid in linesToRemove)
            {
                LabLineEntity lineInDb = GetSpecific<LabLineEntity>(lineGuid);
                m_context.LabLines.Remove(lineInDb);
                labMain.Lines.Remove(lineInDb);
            }
            Update(existingLabLines);
        }
        if (newLabLines.Any())
        {
            Add(newLabLines);
        }
    }
```

Here is the outer call:

```
[HttpPost("")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddOrUpdateLabLine([FromBody] IEnumerable<LabLineEntityViewModel> p_labLinesVM)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState.ToString());
        }
        IEnumerable<LabLineEntity> labLinesE = m_mapper.ViewModelToModel(p_labLinesVM);
        try
        {
            m_repository.AddOrUpdate(labLinesE);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
        if (!(await m_repository.SaveChangesAsync()))
        {
            return BadRequest("Failed to save to the Database (ModelState was ok)");
        }
        List<LabLineEntity> labLinesToReturn = new List<LabLineEntity>();
        foreach (var labLine in labLinesE)
        {
//THIS IS NULL :(
            LabLineEntity lineToAdd = m_repository.GetSpecific<LabLineEntity>(labLine.Id);
            labLinesToReturn.Add(lineToAdd);
        }
        IEnumerable<LabLineEntityViewModel> returnedValue = m_mapper.ModelToViewModel(labLinesToReturn);
        return Created($"Modules/Lab/Forms/Main/", returnedValue);
    }
```

And the SaveChanges:

```
public async Task<bool> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        int rowsChanged = 0;
        try
        {
            rowsChanged = await m_context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // ignored
        }
        return rowsChanged > 0;
    }
```

After this method, the SaveChanges(Async) is called, from an external function (that passed the collection), but the IDs are not populated.

Any solutions?
Regards

Comment: can you show the other parts as well ? I mean `SaveChanges(Async)` and  `external function`.

Comment: just edited the main question :)

Comment: You should not ignore exceptions (SaveChangesAsync). You should at least log the exception.

Comment: You call m_repository.AddOrUpdate but show the implementation of Add. Can you add the implementation of AddOrUpdate ?

Comment: @Guillaume, known, but not implemented yet. And the implementation is up.